# How to run SQL query inside docker container and export results outside the container (.CSV)

Tags: mysql, docker

In SQL server I tried to export a CSV file using below command

```
mysql> mysql -u username -p --host=rdshostname --port=rdsport --batch -e "select * from yourtable" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//' > export.csv
```

But no luck, So How I can export the above query result to CSV file?

Comment: Can you explain what happened when you tried? You got an error message? From your question it's not clear whether this has anything to do with Docker, or perhaps the SQL query just does not produce any results?

Comment: I'd like to run it outside the container, that I can upload this file to my S3 bucket and use AWS DMS to import the .csv file to RDS.  Similar command:  docker exec bc568c22148f /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=123 myexample > backup.sql   - But create .CSV file instead .sql

Comment: I recommend explaining this inside the question body, and also updating the title, maybe to something like "How to run SQL query inside docker container and export results outside the container?". That way the question will be easier to find and more useful to future users.

Comment: Updated the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach is to run the query inside the container and then export the result to file on the host.

```
docker exec -it some-mysql bash -c 'mysql -h myhost -u root -pPassword --database sample --batch -e "select * from company"'
```

This will print the query result, now redirect the resulting output to file on the host.

```
docker exec -it some-mysql bash -c 'mysql -h myhost -u root -pPassword --database sample --batch -e "select * from company"'  > sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//' > company.csv
```

then upload the file to s3 from the host

```
aws s3 cp company.csv s3://mybucket/rds/mydb/table.csv
```

[company sample databse](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/sql-table.php)